# Spring MVC gzip compression

Tags: spring-mvc, gzip

Anyone knows how to enable GZIP compression on Spring MVC's Rest Controllers.
Tomcat has this feature but it will apply to all Restful API's response. I just want to compress HTTP response of certain Restful APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using:
http://www.javablog.fr/javaweb-gzip-compression-protocol-http-filter-gzipresponsewrapper-gzipresponsewrapper.html

And for applying it to certain urls:

```
if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().endsWith("/api/service")){//or similar verification
    //DO compression
}else{
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```